# How to find the pair of lines represented by $x^2-6xy+9y^2+3x-9y=4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My attenpt:-
$x^2-6xy+9y^2+3x-9y=4$
this is the same as

$(x-3y)^2+3(x-3y-\frac{4}{3})=0$

beyon which I'm unable to factorise any further

any advice?

Comment: What is  the pair of lines?

Comment: these lines are parallel, I have to find the distance between them, which is why I'm trying to find the lines

Comment: Try $z=x-3y$ and solve the resulting quadratic (if you can think of nothing better)

Comment: but is there a better way? plugging  each expression to be zero doesn't work, , so can I thus conclude that the lines are x-3y and x-3y-4/3?

Comment: @User, I was actually trying to find the pair of parallel lines represented by this equation

Comment: I didn't understand the question, but your equaation is quadratic. You can find the relation between $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you factor, you get:
$$(x - 3y)^2 + 3(x - 3y) = 4$$
So if you let z = x - 3y, you get:
$$z^2 + 3z - 4 = 0$$
Solving this gives you $z = {-4,1}$, so the two lines modelled by the equation are $-4 = x - 3y$ and $1 = x - 3y.$

Comment: oh, it's as simple as that? Tahnsk!

Comment: +1. My edit was only to add the dollars that you forgot in the last sentence.